# find a string in all files in a directory

Tags: linux, find

I want find `{{text}}` in all files and red in new file. I have tried this but it doesn't work for me

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.dll" -not -name "*.zip" -exec cat {} \; |
    grep "\{.*" | cut -d "{" -f1 | sort | uniq > keys.txt
```

Comment: why don't you try `grep -r text /path/to/dir > out.txt`

Comment: Your attempts to match only a single `{` indicate that you are looking for occurrences of `{text}`.  What do you want to do with `{{ nested {{text}} values}}`?  Or unmatched braces?  Perhaps those issues aren't a concern, in which case you should specify that.

Comment: It seems like you don't really mean "all files", but instead you mean "all files except those ending with `.dll` or `.zip`". [Please be precise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/452211/edit).

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
grep -FIrho '{{text}}' . >/tmp/keys.txt
mv -f /tmp/keys.txt .
```

Or perhaps this if you really need to exclude just `.dll` and `.zip` files:

```
find . \( -name '*.zip -o -name '*.dll' \) -prune -o -type f -exec grep -Fho '{{text}}' {} + >/tmp/keys.txt
mv -f /tmp/keys.txt .
```

Note that `keys.txt` will end up containing zero or more lines of `{{text}}`. Did you perhaps intend to ask to record the file names rather than the matched content? Or maybe the entire line where `{{text}}` is present?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to calling `grep` recursively through shell and `find` magic, some programs can do the tedious work for you.

For example, with silversearcher-ag (https://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) or ack (https://beyondgrep.com/), it's as simple as:

```
ack '{{text}}'
```

or

```
ag '{{text}}'
```

These tools also have the advantage of avoiding searching in binary files or in directories such as `.git`, `.svn` etc. by default and are much faster than calling `grep` in a loop.

These tools are present in the repositories of the major GNU/Linux distributions.